# shape '[58, 2048, -1]' is invalid for input of size 534528

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch. I found a sample code of the capsule network on mnist, I changed it to use my own dataset, but it gives me a runtime error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3248\67117472.py in <module>
    176         train(capsule_net, optimizer,mnist.train_loader, e)
    177         print('start test')
--> 178         test(capsule_net, mnist.test_loader, e)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3248\67117472.py in test(capsule_net, test_loader, epoch)
    142             data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
    143 
--> 144         output, reconstructions, masked = capsule_net(data)
    145         loss = capsule_net.loss(data, output, target, reconstructions)
    146 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3248\1108288962.py in forward(self, data)
    142     def forward(self, data):
    143         #2
--> 144         output = self.digit_capsules(self.primary_capsules(self.conv_layer(data)))
    145         reconstructions, masked = self.decoder(output, data)
    146         return output, reconstructions, masked

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3248\1108288962.py in forward(self, x)
     34         u = [capsule(x) for capsule in self.capsules]
     35         u = torch.stack(u, dim=1)
---> 36         u = u.view(x.size(0), self.num_routes, -1)
     37         return self.squash(u)
     38 

RuntimeError: shape '[58, 2048, -1]' is invalid for input of size 534528
```

The image size is 32*32. Could anyone tell me how to fix this error?

There are 3 layers, Cov layer, primary caps and digit caps. The train dataset contains 100 images and the test dataset includes 20 images.

```
class ConvLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=256, kernel_size=9):
        super(ConvLayer, self).__init__()

        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                              out_channels=out_channels,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              stride=1
                              )

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.relu(self.conv(x))


class PrimaryCaps(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_capsules=8, in_channels=256, out_channels=32, kernel_size=9, num_routes=32 * 6 * 6):
        super(PrimaryCaps, self).__init__()
        self.num_routes = num_routes
        self.capsules = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=2, padding=0)
            for _ in range(num_capsules)])

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x)
        u = [capsule(x) for capsule in self.capsules]
        u = torch.stack(u, dim=1)
        u = u.view(x.size(0), self.num_routes, -1)
        return self.squash(u)

    def squash(self, input_tensor):
        # take norm of input vectors
        squared_norm = (input_tensor ** 2).sum(-1, keepdim=True)
        output_tensor = squared_norm * input_tensor / ((1. + squared_norm) * torch.sqrt(squared_norm))
        return output_tensor


class DigitCaps(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_capsules=10, num_routes=32 * 6 * 6, in_channels=8, out_channels=16):
        super(DigitCaps, self).__init__()

        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.num_routes = num_routes
        self.num_capsules = num_capsules

        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, num_routes, num_capsules, out_channels, in_channels))

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)            
        x = torch.stack([x] * self.num_capsules, dim=2).unsqueeze(4)

        W = torch.cat([self.W] * batch_size, dim=0)
        u_hat = torch.matmul(W, x)    
        b_ij = Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.num_routes, self.num_capsules, 1))
        if USE_CUDA:
            b_ij = b_ij.cuda()

        num_iterations = 3
        for iteration in range(num_iterations):
            c_ij = F.softmax(b_ij, dim=1)
            c_ij = torch.cat([c_ij] * batch_size, dim=0).unsqueeze(4)

            s_j = (c_ij * u_hat).sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            v_j = self.squash(s_j)

            if iteration < num_iterations - 1:
                a_ij = torch.matmul(u_hat.transpose(3, 4), torch.cat([v_j] * self.num_routes, dim=1))
                b_ij = b_ij + a_ij.squeeze(4).mean(dim=0, keepdim=True)

        return v_j.squeeze(1)

    def squash(self, input_tensor):
        squared_norm = (input_tensor ** 2).sum(-1, keepdim=True)
        output_tensor = squared_norm * input_tensor / ((1. + squared_norm) * torch.sqrt(squared_norm))
        return output_tensor


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_width=28, input_height=28, input_channel=1):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.input_width = input_width
        self.input_height = input_height
        self.input_channel = input_channel
        self.reconstraction_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(16 * 10, 512),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(1024, self.input_height * self.input_width * self.input_channel),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x, data):
        classes = torch.sqrt((x ** 2).sum(2))
        classes = F.softmax(classes, dim=0)

        _, max_length_indices = classes.max(dim=1)
        masked = Variable(torch.sparse.torch.eye(10))
        if USE_CUDA:
            masked = masked.cuda()
        masked = masked.index_select(dim=0, index=Variable(max_length_indices.squeeze(1).data))
        t = (x * masked[:, :, None, None]).view(x.size(0), -1)
        reconstructions = self.reconstraction_layers(t)
        reconstructions = reconstructions.view(-1, self.input_channel, self.input_width, self.input_height)
        return reconstructions, masked


class CapsNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        super(CapsNet, self).__init__()
        if config:
            self.conv_layer = ConvLayer(config.cnn_in_channels, config.cnn_out_channels, config.cnn_kernel_size)
            print(self.conv_layer)
            self.primary_capsules = PrimaryCaps(config.pc_num_capsules, config.pc_in_channels, config.pc_out_channels,
                                               config.pc_kernel_size, config.pc_num_routes)
            print(self.primary_capsules)
            self.digit_capsules = DigitCaps(config.dc_num_capsules, config.dc_num_routes, config.dc_in_channels,
                                            config.dc_out_channels)
            print(self.digit_capsules)
            self.decoder = Decoder(config.input_width, config.input_height, config.cnn_in_channels)
            print(self.decoder)
        else:
            self.conv_layer = ConvLayer()
            self.primary_capsules = PrimaryCaps()
            self.digit_capsules = DigitCaps()
            self.decoder = Decoder()

        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()

    def forward(self, data):
        output = self.digit_capsules(self.primary_capsules(self.conv_layer(data)))
        reconstructions, masked = self.decoder(output, data)
        return output, reconstructions, masked
```

following is the related part of main function

```
for e in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
        transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])
       
        train(capsule_net, optimizer,mnist.train_loader, e)
        print('start test')
        test(capsule_net, mnist.test_loader, e)
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code!

Comment: @Ivan I edited the question to add the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reshape your tensor in your `forward` method of your `PrimaryCaps` class. However, you are trying to reshape it as `[58, 2048, -1]` but you have a size of `534528`. `534528`  is not a multiple of `58*2048`. My guess is that the value of your `self.num_routes` is supposed to be of `32 * 6 * 6`, but somewhere in your code you are defining it as `2048`.

```
class PrimaryCaps(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_capsules=8, in_channels=256, out_channels=32, kernel_size=9, num_routes=32 * 6 * 6):
        ...

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x)
        u = [capsule(x) for capsule in self.capsules]
        u = torch.stack(u, dim=1)
        u = u.view(x.size(0), self.num_routes, -1) #HERE
        return self.squash(u)
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT : You're probably setting the wrong value on this line

```
self.primary_capsules = PrimaryCaps(config.pc_num_capsules, config.pc_in_channels, config.pc_out_channels,
                                           config.pc_kernel_size, config.pc_num_routes)
```

where `config.pc_num_routes` is probably set to 2048, which overrides your value of `32 * 6 * 6`.